# Understanding behavior of index_put in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to understand the behavior of `index_put` in PyTorch, but the document is not clear to me.

Given

```
a = torch.zeros(2, 3)
a.index_put([torch.tensor(1, 0), torch.tensor([1, 1])], torch.tensor(1.))
```

it returns

```
tensor([[1., 1., 0.], 
       [0., 0., 0.])
```

While given

```
a = torch.zeros(2, 3)
a.index_put([torch.tensor(0, 0), torch.tensor([1, 1])], torch.tensor(1.))
```

it returns

```
tensor([[0., 1., 0.], 
       [0., 0., 0.])
```

I am wondering what the rule of `index_put` on earth? What if I want to put three values to a, such that it returns

```
tensor([0., 1., 1.,],
       [0., 1., 0.])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your examples here with argument names inserted, fixed brackets and correct output(yours was swapped):

```
a.index_put(indices=[torch.tensor([1, 0]), torch.tensor([1, 1])], values=torch.tensor(1.))

tensor([[0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.]])

a.index_put(indices=[torch.tensor([0, 0]), torch.tensor([0, 1])], values = torch.tensor(1.))

tensor([[1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]
```

What this method does is inserting value(s) into locations in the original `a` tensor indicated by `indices`. indices is a list of x coordinates of insertions and y coordinates of insertions. values may be single value or a 1d tensor.

to obtain the desired output use:

```
a.index_put(indices=[torch.tensor([0,0,1]), torch.tensor([1, 2, 1])], values=torch.tensor(1.))

tensor([[0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]])
```

moreover, you can pass multiple values in `values` argument to insert them into the indicated positions:

```
a.index_put(indices=[torch.tensor([0,0,1]), torch.tensor([1, 2, 1])], values=torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.]))

tensor([[0., 1., 2.],
        [0., 3., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sorry that I have wrongly copied second example. Do you know why `a.index_put([torch.tensor([0, 0]), torch.tensor([1, 1])], torch.tensor(1.))` outputs `tensor([[0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 0.])` ?

Comment: in your example you effectively pass same index  twice: dimension 0 is [0,0]  and dimension 1 is [1,1].